# Declaration of the function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

What do I declare with the following definition:

```
void (*bar)(A*){ }; //1
```

My first thought was that I declare and define function pointer and a function the pointer point to. But it's wrong, because any call to the `bar()` leads to a segmentation fault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct A{ };

void foo(A*){ std:cout << "foo" << std::endl; }

void (*bar)(){ };

int main(){
    bar();
}
```

Moreover, I can't imbed any statement into the "definition":

```
void (*bar)(A*){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl };
```

yeilds compile-time error.

So, what does the declaration `//1` mean?

Answer (score 4):

This statement:

```
void (*bar)(A*){ };
```

declares a variable named `bar` of type `void(*)(A*)`, ie "pointer to function taking pointer to A and returning void", and *zero-initializes* it. Thus, it's equivalent to this:

```
void (*bar)(A*) = nullptr;
```

Obviously, when calling this `bar`, a segfault should be no surprise.

It's not possible to declare a function and a pointer to that function in a single declaration.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same as setting it to `nullptr`? default-initializing variables hasn't set them to `0` for as long as I've known. I'd have thought it pointed to a garbage address.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: That is true if you declare a pointer without initializing it.  But if you *default-initialize* it, it is zeroed.

Comment: Default-initialization is different from no initialization.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode you're actually right, [`default-initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) of non-class variables gives indeterminate values (see the notes section). Here we actually got [`value-initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) due to the `{}` at the end, which sets it to `nullptr`. But that's just standardese wording and being pedantic.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl god-damn knew it. Didn't realize `{}` would value initialize to `0` though...

Comment: @CoffeeandCode we got case "4) Otherwise, the object is zero-initialized." for non-class, non-array types, and [`zero-initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) gives it "If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T." which is basically `nullptr` if you're interested in the exact initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have declared a function pointer that points to nothing at the moment. You should able to validate that using a debugger.

```
void (*bar)(A*){ }; //1
```

You could make the pointer point to a function like this:

```
void foo(A*){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl };
bar = &foo;
```

And call it like this now:

```
A a;
bar(&a);
```

Full snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

void (*bar)(A*){};

void foo(A*) { std::cout << " foo " << std::endl;}

int main() {
    A a;
    bar = &foo;
    bar(&a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
void (*bar)(A*){ }; //1
```

it means "bar" is a function pointer which can point to some function which takes "A*" as parameter.

In your case, it is not pointing to any function yet.
to make it working use,

```
void (*bar)(A*) = foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be changed to the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct A{ };

void foo(A*){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }

void (*bar)(A*);


int main(){
    A a;
    bar = &foo;    
    bar(&a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To declare an actual function, get rid of the `(*)` portion around the function name:

```
void bar(A*){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl };
```

https://ideone.com/UPIYxg

> So, what does the declaration `//1` mean?

It is just a comment.

Comment: I think he means that whole line, not just `//1`. It's an empty assignment/initialization.

Comment: Does that even compile? Surely it must be `(A* a)`?

Comment: @M.Shaw, you can have unnamed parameters - perfectly legal.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: That is not what stella *asked*.  I answered what was *asked*, and provided a fix for the segfault error.  Why was this downvoted?

Comment: You didn't answer the question. "It is just a comment"... that wasn't the question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't downvote you, I'm just saying that's probably not what OP meant.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Then the OP needs to learn how to ask what they mean. We are not hear to interpret what an asker *means* to ask, we are here to answer what is *actually* asked.

Comment: It seemed pretty clear to me that `//1` was intended as a label to refer to the preceding declaration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Idk man, I thought it was pretty clear that he meant `//1` as a label for that line. But you're right, he definitely should have said explicitly that.